# Corrigir tags sobre OOP e sinônimos

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Para a pergunta.

[Chamada de método direto na instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10591/chamada-de-metodo-direto-na-instancia?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Alguém com permissões necessárias para deixar como sinônimos as tags, OOP, POO, Orientação a Objetos, OO e Programação Orientada a Objetos ?
A [poo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo) ainda não esta como sinônimo.

Comment: não existem tags `oo` e `Programação Orientada a Objetos`

Comment: Sim, ainda não exite. Mas poo existe. Neste caso qual o procedimento, criar as tags sinônimos todas de uma vez ou enquanto elas vão aparecendo se faz a ligação com as outras?

Comment: conforme forem aparecendo fazemos as ligações; quanto a `poo`, realmente deve ser marcada como sinonimo

Comment: A pergunta é: nós **queremos** tantos sinônimos para `orientação-a-objetos`? Vale a pena ter uma tag para "programação OO", "análise OO" e "arquitetura OO"? Siglas em inglês e português? Concordo que a tag já existente `poo` pode ser marcada como sinônimo, mas talvez fosse o caso até de excluí-la, não sei... Abri [uma nova pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1130/215) para debater o caso de abreviaturas.

Comment: A propósito: a tradução "correta" para *object-oriented* é "orientada **por** objetos" - os objetos são **aquilo que orientam** sua programação, não **para onde** sua programação está orientada. Mas a expressão "orientação **a** objetos" está tão enraizada no nosso vocabulário que pode ser considerada "vencedora por maioria de votos" rsrs. (mas se formos incluir tantos sinõnimos, eu faço questão dessa forma alternativa também - eu tento não ser purista/pedante, mas sempre que eu estou escrevendo algo de minha autoria eu gosto de usar essa forma)

Comment: A tag [tag:poo] existe, e sugeri que seja tratada como sinônima de [tag:orientação-a-objetos]. Quem tiver pontos suficientes na tag pode votar a favor ou contra a proposta de sinônimo aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos/synonyms

Comment: @bfavaretto e o [TAG:OOP]? Já temos 6 perguntas com essa tag, não deveria ser sinônimo também? Ps: já votei no sinônimo para `poo`, falta um voto para virar sinônimo.

Comment: @Math Alguém sugeriu (você?). Eu não tinha pontos suficientes na tag pra sugerir.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, fui eu que sugeri. Como você sugeriu `poo` mas não pode sugerir `oop`? Você precisa ter pontuação em `orientação-a-objetos`, não é? Eu tb não tenho nenhuma pontuação em `oop`.

Comment: Precisa ter pontuação (2 pontos, acho) nas duas pontas (principal e sinônimo) @Math

Comment: Só se eu consegui no passado e mudaram a tag, seilá, só sei que está dada a sugestão ;-)

Comment: E tenho quase certeza de que quando sugeri poo como sinônimo, oop nem existia como tag, e ambas precisam existir. Pode ter sido só isso, @Math