# Em que situações uma abreviatura deve ser usada como tag?

Tags: debate, tags, padronização

Normalmente as tags - [mesmo com mais de uma palavra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/443/215) - são sempre escritas **por extenso**, entretanto há algumas **abreviaturas** [em uso no site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/903/215), e [outras sendo propostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1126/215). Não encontrei em nenhum lugar nenhum *guideline* e/ou uma discussão sobre o assunto, portanto pergunto:

- Devemos incluir (como sinônimos) abreviações comuns para tags, quando elas não existem?
- Devemos *mantê-las* quando elas **já existem**?
- O que é considerado uma "boa abreviação", aquela que encontra uso corriqueiro?
- Se duas ou mais tecnologias ou conceitos são conhecidos pela mesma abreviatura, qual deve ter preferência, a mais "popular"?

Comment: Outra questão: deveria haver sinônimos também de tags ou siglas notórias em inglês como é o caso de OOP?

Comment: @iuristona excelente pergunta. Minha opinião é que sim, devemos criar esses sinonimos, pois inglês é algo extremamente enraizado em programação logo esses termos aparecerão com relativa frequencia.

Answer (score 4):

Devemos sempre usar o nome mais completo e descritivo para as tags (sem se alongar claro, três palavras já é muito). Tendo isso em vista, os sinônimos servem como uma forma automatizada de o sistema substituir as formas abreviadas que são muito usadas pela forma "correta", que todos devem usar.

Mas não há motivo para incluir sinônimos para coisas que não são usadas com frequência. Se ocorreu em um caso isolado, mais simples é editar a pergunta e corrigir. Mas caso a forma abreviada comece a ser usada por muitos perguntadores, então sim cabe criar um sinônimo. Portanto:

[js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js)→[javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
[rb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rb)→[ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)
[oo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oo)→[orientação-a-objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos) ("programação" não é necessário)
[poo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo)→[orientação-a-objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos)
[ie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie)→[internet-explorer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) ("microsoft" não é necessário)
...